# Trying to add two values from different javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, math

I am deriving two different values from these scripts.

**Script #1...**

```
//JS for Potential Gen Ed TOC
$(function($) {
    $('#CourseMenu select').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#CourseMenu select').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseFloat(elm.value, 10);
        });

     $('#total_potential').html(Math.min(sum,72).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

**Script #2...**

```
//JS for Potential Gen Ed TOC from Electives only
$(function($) {
    $('#CourseMenu_Electives select').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#CourseMenu_Electives select').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseFloat(elm.value, 10);
        });

     $('#total_potential').html(Math.min(sum,33).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

**However, I'd like to pull the data from both of these and have the result display in the following HTML...**

```
   <p><fieldset id="PotentialTOC">
      <legend style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 140%;">Potential TOC Evaluation Results</legend>

      <div id="Results" style="text-align:left; font-family: 'Century Gothic', Gadget, sans-serif; font-size:14px;"><br />
        <div>
          <h2><span id="span"></span>
        Potential Gen Ed TOC:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="total_potential"></span>
        <br />
        Potential Money Saved: $<span id="total_money"></span>
        <br />
        Potential Class Time Saved:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="total_time"></span> weeks
</fieldset></p>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/fhL3s/1/) to show what I've done so far... I can't transfer more than 33 elective credits and no more than 72 credits overall. I have the scripts laid out well, but again, need them combined to spit out one value.

Answer (score 0):

The first thought that came to mind was to store the result of each function in a hidden div (or even displayed, so a user can see the weight of each choice). Then update the total value by just adding the two columns that contribute to it after the new credit total has been calculated for the new choice.

It will be a minor change, just alter where the current values are being inserted and add an additional line or two to each change callback that pulls in those two values, parses them, adds them, and then updates the total div.

I thought about doing it altogether, just using the previous value from the div, but the problem I ran into was that you weren't sure what the previous contribution was so it made it hard to "zero" the div before adding in the new choice since the choices are not cumulative. One select box should only make one contribution to the final value.

Edit:

So I fiddled with the fiddle and went with the state object approach: http://jsfiddle.net/MCg2d/1

```
COURSE['Non-electives'] = Math.min(sum, 72).toFixed(2);
var total = (parseFloat(COURSE['Non-electives'], 10) || 0) + (parseFloat(COURSE['Electives'], 10) || 0)
$('#total_potential').html(total);
});
```

It's very rough but it probably makes more sense than my ramblings above.

Comment: I thought about that, but wasn't sure if it was the best option. I'll give it a shot. Welcome to Stack!

Comment: Another option would be to introduce a global variable that holds application state. Something like YOURAPPNAME = {}. This way you can share state across the two functions. I just leaned toward the HTML solution since I thought it may improve user experience.

Comment: Matter of fact... user experience matters more here than anything else. I'll start with the HTML way.

Comment: Where did you get the term 'Non_electives' from? I tried placing this in my code exactly the way you laid it out and it didn't work. Did you add something to it that I might not realize?

Comment: I also noticed that you didn't account for the fact that the Electives count cannot exceed 33 overall. Total credits between Electives and Non-Electives cannot exceed 72.

Comment: Non-electives just popped into my head as one was referred to as electives. The COURSE['Non-electives'] and COURSE['Electives'] could be named anything. They are just the keys in our JS object that refer to the values each of those select drop downs maps to.

I somehow didn't include account for the sum in Electives. Oops. Updated my fiddle with that.